# Functions or buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a program that saves the current URL on click of a button
(Its for a chrome extension, I want to let pc builders save the URLs of their parts without making a million bookmarks)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>

<script type="javascript" src="buttonsact.js"> 


</script>



<button type="button" onclick="changeCPU()">Change CPU</button><h5 id=CPU>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeMOTH()">Change Motherboard</button><h5 id=MOTH   id=part>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeHARD()">Change Hard Drive</button><h5 id=HARD>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeRAM()">Change RAM</button><h5 id=RAM>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeGPU()">Change GPU</button><h5 id=GPU>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeCASE()">Change Case</button><h5 id=CASE>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changePOWER()">Change Power Unit</button><h5 id=POWER>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="changeMON()">Change Monitor</button><h5 id=MON>Not Selected Yet</h5>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">!!!!RESET!!!!</button>



</body>
</html>
```

---

**Javascript:**

---

```
function getpage()
{
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    var tablink = tab.url;
})
}

function changeCPU()
{
x=document.getElementById("CPU");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeMOTH()
{
x=document.getElementById("MOTH");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeRAM()
{
x=document.getElementById("RAM");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeHARD()
{
x=document.getElementById("HARD");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeGPU()
{
x=document.getElementById("GPU");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeCASE()
{
x=document.getElementById("CASE");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changePOWER()
{
x=document.getElementById("POWER");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}

function changeMON()
{
x=document.getElementById("MON");  // Find the element
x.innerHTML=tablink;    // Change the content
}


function reset()
{
a=document.getElementById("CPU");  // Find the element
b=document.getElementById("MOTH");
c=document.getElementById("HARD");
d=document.getElementById("RAM");
e=document.getElementById("GPU");
f=document.getElementById("CASE");
g=document.getElementById("POWER");
h=document.getElementById("MON");

a.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";    // Change the content
b.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
c.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
d.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
e.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
f.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
g.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
h.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";
}

window.onload = getpage()
```

I tested it to see if it was just something about my code to capture the URL by changing this: 
`a.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet";    // Change the content`

to this 
`a.innerHTML="Not Selected Yet Yet";    // Change the content`

And hitting reset. This still didn't work. I think something about how my program calls the function. I did get it to work originally, but i'm not sure how I changed it. Thank You!

Comment: Can you post a live demo to reproduce the problem? Any error in the console?

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify event handlers with the `onclick` attribute in a page that is part of an extension. You need to bind your events using javascript (with `addEventListener` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the fact that the variable tablink is outside of the scope of all the change functions. Try defining it outside the getpage function and THEN assigning the value inside.

Comment: I did that, but still the buttons won't work. I think it has to do with the buttons as well. Thanks for telling me about that as well though!

Comment: A couple of things on your HTML might be messing with the code. You might want to surround the IDs of the h5 tags with quotes. And you also have two IDs inside the motherboard element.
Also do you have any console errors when clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

`var tablink` inside the `getpage()` function is limited to the scope of that function and is therefore undefined when you set the innerHTML values. Change it to a global by removing the `var` keyword or define it outside the `getpage()` function.

Comment: I did that, but still the buttons won't work. I think it has to do with the buttons as well. Thanks for telling me about that as well though!